# Typescript How to make public static member variable readable

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, winston

I am writing node application using typescript and using winston for logging.

I have created a "Logger" class with "logger" member and "init()" member function. As I am exporting "Logger" class, I know that we can access "logger" member in another file.

```
import winston from "winston";

class Logger {

    public static logger: any;

    public static init():any {
    this.logger = winston.createLogger({
        level: 'info',
        format: winston.format.json(),
        defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
        transports: [              
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
          new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
        ],
    });
}

export default Logger;
```

I am accessing this Logger class as below.

```
import Logger from './Logger'

Logger.init();
//access logger member here...
```

After I initialise "logger" member using Logger.init(), I want "logger" member only to be readable. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Why do you need this class wrapper at all? Just `export const logger = winston.createLogger ...`

Comment: And if you want to use the class then you should use constructor to initialize and `new Logger` instead of `Logger.init()`

Comment: You can make the property private and use a getter.  You could declare `public static readonly logger` BUT this won't work with the current setup because you would need to move the assignment into the constructor, which is doable.  Is this meant to be a singleton class?

Comment: Ditch the `any`! Your types should be `init(): void` and `logger: winston.Logger | undefined`.  But with a better design (assigning logger in the constructor) you can avoid the possible `undefined`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste: Yes, this is meant to be singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to keep the config of winston immutable throughout the application, a solution could be:

```
import winston, { Logger as WinstonLogger } from 'winston'; // Rename the original interface from winston

export type Logger = Pick<WinstonLogger, 'log'>; // Create a new interface that only exposes the `log` method

const logger: Logger = winston.createLogger({...}) // Configure your winston instance

export default logger; // Now methods other then `log` cannot be called outside of this file
```